# image couldn't load an image view in json using imageview

Tags: android, json, imageview

*the image couldn't load an image view but other values are successfully loading.only image not loaded my full code is here anybody can tell the answer please!!., I'm using glide but not loading the image.the image couldn't load an image view in JSON using image view  *

****Hostel.jav**

```
  public class Hostel {
             private String image;


            public Hostel(String image,


                this.timestamp = timestamp;
            }



            public String getName() {
                return String.valueOf( name );
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

          public String getMobile2() {
                return mobile2;
            }

            public void setMobile2(String mobile2) {
                this.mobile2 = mobile2;
            }

            public String getAddress() {
                return address;
            }

            public void setAddress(String address) {
                this.address = address;
            }

            public String getPlace() {
                return place;
            }





        }
```

Comment: 151662222695556.jpg image url not correct

Comment: where is your image and url?

Comment: Please provide minimalistic samples with only code and data relevant to the problem you are describing!

Comment: There is no URL for the image in your JSON. Update your JSON to get fully qualified image URL.

Answer (score 2):

You should either use... **"yoururl"** or your **drawable** with glide.. like

```
Glide.with(GroupChatMemberListActivity.this)
         .load("url")
         .placeholder(drawable)
         .into(holder.imageView);
```

**OR** *your drawable resource*

```
Glide.with(GroupChatMemberListActivity.this)
         .load(R.drawable.your_drawable)
         .placeholder(drawable)
         .into(holder.imageView);
```

> **"xyz.png"** is neither a **(int)** drawable resource nor a valid image URL

Answer (score 0):

You need to have URL of the image in the format 
http://serverIP/ott/public/api/imagefolder/151660038947843.png

if you are using local host

http://localhost/ott/public/api/imagefolder/151660038947843.png